# Trouble installing OpenCV with Cmake

Tags: macos, opencv, unix, cmake

I am trying to install the openCV library for Python however I am new to CMake and have run into some trouble after having cloned the repository in ~/opencv.

I've made a build directory in it with the mkdir command however once inside it when trying to set CMake options in it.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

I get prompted with the following error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/eDen/opencv/build/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local" does not exist.
```

Comment: You forget the last argument for `cmake` which points to the *source directory*.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm trying to call cmake from my build dir.  which is the folder I created in the source that I reursively cloned from git.                                               cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/myInstallfolder ../                                                            Regardless what I try I have an error sayin in source builds are not allowed, asking me to create a build folder. Last argument to the source directory didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't making the right directory, some Mac OS X installations doesn't include /usr/local/. You can make the directory using, if it's not already created, with:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/
```

But you say you want to use OpenCV with Python. I recommend you to obtain an already compiled copy unless you need some advanced features not available in the compiled version, like Qt integration or CUDA programming. But these features are included in the arguments of the cmake command.

Instructions on how to obtain OpenCV from Homebrew repository, [this page](http://www.mobileway.net/2015/02/14/install-opencv-for-python-on-mac-os-x/) explains the process. Basically, you install Homebrew, then Python, configure it and install some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev mentioned in the comments, you need to specify the path to *source directory* (i.e. where the main *CMakeLists.txt* file exists) at the end of your command. So, supposing you are now in the build directory, the final `cmake` command would be as follows:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the last argument as `..` but still get the error.

In my case, there is a bad whitespace in the above arguments. So the last `..` is ignored.